# Magento2 overide payment block

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

Im want to add error message in payment block when Cash on delivery payment method is not available

http://prntscr.com/iqh8sj

Can anyone help how can i do it in magento2

Comment: you want the message to appear after the user clicks place order?  or you just want to add a message next to the payment method? or you want to make that radio disable + add a message?

Comment: radio disable + add a message

Comment: Is it Possible??

Comment: if add a message next to the payment method is possible than tell me